# Adding and extracting a certificate string in yml file

Tags: python, yaml

I have a standard .crt string I'd like to add as a string in a YAML configuration file and I want to be able to extract it from there with its structure intact using Python. What happens now is it's being extracted flat and without line breaks I have there.

crt file example:

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Answer (score 2):

When you edit your cfg file, assuming you put it after key `crt` make sure you specify a literal block style scalar using `|2`

```
crt: |2
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
  MIIGOTCCBCGgAwIBAgIJAOE/vJd8EB24MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBQUAMIGyMQswCQYD
  VQQGEwJGUjEPMA0GA1UECAwGQWxzYWNlMRMwEQYDVQQHDApTdHJhc2JvdXJnMRgw
  FgYDVQQKDA93d3cuZnJlZWxhbi5vcmcxEDAOBgNVBAsMB2ZyZWVsYW4xLTArBgNV
  BAMMJEZyZWVsYW4gU2FtcGxlIENlcnRpZmljYXRlIEF1dGhvcml0eTEiMCAGCSqG
  SIb3DQEJARYTY29udGFjdEBmcmVlbGFuLm9yZzAeFw0xMjA0MjcxMDE3NDRaFw0x
  ....
```

The `2` is necessary as your first line starts with spaces (you can of course indent the body with any positive number, as long as you specify the right amount after `|`).

Without the `|` your scalar is interpreted as a multi-line plain scalar and on loading newlines in those will be replaced by spaces

The above should be preserved when doing a `round_trip_load()` and `round_trip_dump()`

Comment: Why nobody has voted on this. It is so correct! (life saving solution)